# razer_hydra hydra.launch hangs on "starting stream"

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I recently upgraded my `razer_hydra` install to the indigo branch, and made sure that the udev rules were properly installed.  Now when I run the command:

```
roslaunch razer_hydra hydra.launch publish_tf:=true
```

I get the output:

```
process[razer_hydra_driver-1]: started with pid [8245]
[ INFO] [1405699624.237070758]: Using filter corner frequency of 3.0 Hz
[ INFO] [1405699624.255034176]: Setting pivot offset [0.040, 0.000, 0.000]
[ INFO] [1405699624.255136486]: Setting grab offset [0.120, 0.000, 0.000]
[ INFO] [1405699624.255200864]: Sending messages using the 'grab' frame.
[ INFO] [1405699624.255261153]: Publishing frame data to TF.
[ INFO] [1405699624.279980897]: opening hydra on /dev/hydra
[ INFO] [1405699624.280525075]: starting stream... (first packet takes a few seconds)
```

and the process hangs there.

Has anyone else had this problem? When I was using the hydro branch, things worked fine.

Thanks!
Kel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187048/razer_hydra-hydra.launch-hangs-on-%22starting-stream%22/) by [Kel](https://answers.ros.org/users/1972/kel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2014-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the code:

https://github.com/aleeper/razer_hydra/blob/indigo-devel/nodes/hydra_node.cpp

It's working just as intended. Have you checked that you can rostopic echo joy

?

---

Originally posted by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) with karma: 644 on 2014-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kel](https://answers.ros.org/users/1972/kel/) on 2014-07-18**:
So I didn't realize that the line of code was removed that said something like "First message recieved, everything should be working now"
However, I get nothing from
rostopic echo /hydra_joy

**Comment by [Kel](https://answers.ros.org/users/1972/kel/) on 2014-07-18**:
Could this be a problem with the udev rules?  When I downloaded the source and catkin_made, it did not place the 99-hydra-indigo in my udev folder.  I had to do it manually.

**Comment by [Kel](https://answers.ros.org/users/1972/kel/) on 2014-07-18**:
Ok, so I blew away my build and devel and catkin_make again.  I also switched from the ros fork to you aleeper git, and it works fine.  So not sure if it was my environment or something in the hydro-devel branch of the ros fork.  Probably my workspace :)
Thanks for the help!

**Comment by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on 2014-07-18**:
All you my friend.